How many Nvidia A40's are needed to load a Llama 3 model?
I am trying to run a Llama3 70B model on two (or three) Nvidia A40s. Since it works on a single A100 with around 80GB memory, I expected it to work on two A40s with 48GB each, but I got a out-of-memory issue. Strangely, the same happens with 3 A40's. I wonder if the code correctly distributes the model between the GPUs. It looks like it creates three copies, which is not how the documentation describes it. How many A40's are required in principle?
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM

model_id = 'meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-70B-Instruct'

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_id, device_map="auto", load_in_4bit=True
)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id, padding_side="left")
model_inputs = tokenizer(["A list of colors: red, blue"], return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")

generated_ids = model.generate(**model_inputs)
answer = tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]

print('Answer:\n', answer)

torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 896.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 44.34 GiB of which 510.19 MiB is free. Process 21422 has 14.61 GiB memory in use. Process 21423 has 14.61 GiB memory in use. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 14.61 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 14.35 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 1.78 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management  (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#environment-variables)
    new_value = value.to(device)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 896.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 44.34 GiB of which 510.19 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 14.61 GiB memory in use. Process 21423 has 14.61 GiB memory in use. Process 21424 has 14.61 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 14.35 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 1.78 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management  (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#environment-variables)
    new_value = value.to(device)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 896.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 44.34 GiB of which 510.19 MiB is free. Process 21422 has 14.61 GiB memory in use. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 14.61 GiB memory in use. Process 21424 has 14.61 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 14.35 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 1.78 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management  (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#environment-variables)
srun: error: gpu03: task 1: Exited with exit code 1

I tried it with and without 4bit quantization.
